# Direct .pyc files to different directories when .py script is run

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I direct the .pyc files that are created to a different directory when the script is run? I'm running python 2.7.3 if it matters. They just clutter up my files when I run my .py files.

Comment: @SomeGuy: the answer for 2.7 is the same as for 3.0 and 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. `.pyc` files can *only* be written to the same location as the source file.

Python 3.2 moved to a `__pycache__` subdirectory instead. Neither option is configurable.

At best you can disable bytecode files being written by either removing write access to the directory, setting the [`-B` command line option](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-B) when you run Python, or setting the [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE).